# Using minitest-reporters with TeamCity (minitest-reporters tries to override reporter selection)

Tags: teamcity, minitest

Does anyone have experience with using minitest-reporters for correct test output on TeamCity?

I want to use the JUnit reporter and when I am running the `rake test` task on my computer, the output is correctly in xml format under test/reports. But when I run the tests from TeamCity, then it tries to use the RubyMine reporter instead (although test_helper specifies JUnit reporter). I found that reports.rb file from mintiest-reporters has these lines:

```
 def self.choose_reporters(console_reporters, env)
  if env["TM_PID"]
    [RubyMateReporter.new]
  elsif env["RM_INFO"] || env["TEAMCITY_VERSION"]
    [RubyMineReporter.new]
  else
    Array(console_reporters)
  end
end
```

And it seems that here the RubiMine reporter is chosen by default when these environment variables are given, although I specified another reprter in my test_helper (and it seems that I could not use the RubiMine reporter as it tries to require some TeamCity files and they somehow cannot be accessed).

I tried to override `TEAMCITY_VERSION` while calling `rake test` but it does not seem to work.

Has anyone solved this problem? Or is there some other reporter gem that would work better (I also tried ci_reporter, as it works with my other projects with lower ruby versions but somehow not with 2.0.0)?

Comment: While not going down exactly the same path as you, I tried to use Minitest with TeamCity 8.0.5 a few months ago but gave up.  We are currently using Test::Unit, but may come back to this later on.



According to this support note: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-19055#comment=27-335987, Minitest is supposed to be supported from TeamCity 7.1, using the minitest-reporters gem but the documentation is not yet complete.   The referenced documentation in the support note comment is for IntelliJ - not TeamCity.

Comment: Note also this comment in the above referenced support comment:
'Proper minitest support cannot be done because minitest does not support injecting formatters.'

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem today and was able to solve it by unsetting the 3 environment variables before executing the rake task.

For example, I have a TeamCity command line build step that basically looks like this:

```sh
#! /bin/bash
unset TM_PID
unset RM_INFO
unset TEAMCITY_VERSION
rake my_task
```